# In ASP.NET an excel is downloaded using Response.end and a client side javascript loader is provided. which im able to show but unable to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel

After `response.end()` client script never works. Is there any alternative way to show hide loader when `Response.write` and `Response.end` is used?

Answer (score 0):

A common method is to set a cookie on the server before calling `Response.End()`

`HttpCookie fileDownloadToken = new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", "1");`

and then create an interval to check for the presence of that cookie

```
 function btnSubmit_Click() {

    // Show loader
    // Submit to server

    fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        if ($.cookie('fileDownloadToken') == '1') {
            window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
            $.removeCookie('fileDownloadToken', { path: '/' });

            // Hide loading panel here
        }
     }, 1250);
}
```